# BMI calc App flutter by Angela from app brewary. No Such Method '>=' was called on null ,

Tags: flutter

I am doing BMI calculator App by Angel From App brewary.
i am creating new object as calc and giving value of constructor height and weight but in calculator_brain.dart the value of _bmi is still null. if I initialize _bmi value with a number it works fine.

my input_page.dart is

```
bottonButton(
        buttonTitle: 'Calculate',
        onTap: () {
          CalculatorBrain calc =
              CalculatorBrain(Getheight: height, Getweight: weight);
          Navigator.push(
            context,
            MaterialPageRoute(
              builder: ((context) => ResultsPage(
                    interpritation: calc.getInterpritation(),
                    ResultText: calc.getResult(),
                    bmiResults: calc.CalculateBMI(),
                  )),
            ),
          );
        },
      ),
```

My ResultPage is as follows

```
class ResultsPage extends StatelessWidget {
  ResultsPage({this.bmiResults, this.ResultText, this.interpritation});
  final String bmiResults;
  final String ResultText;
  final String interpritation;
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        title: Text('BMI Calculator'),
      ),
      body: Column(
        mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.stretch,
        children: [
          Expanded(
            child: Container(
              padding: EdgeInsets.only(top: 20),
              child: Center(
                child: Text(
                  'Your Result',
                  style: TextStyle(fontSize: 50, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
          Expanded(
            flex: 4,
            child: ReusableCard(
              Colour: kactiveCardColor,
              label: '',
              onPress: () {},
              cardChild: Column(
                  mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.spaceEvenly,
                  crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.center,
                  children: [
                    Text(
                      ResultText.toUpperCase(),
                      style: TextStyle(
                        color: Color(0xFF24D876),
                        fontSize: 22,
                        fontWeight: FontWeight.bold,
                      ),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      bmiResults,
                      style:
                          TextStyle(fontSize: 100, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
                    ),
                    Text(
                      interpritation,
                      textAlign: TextAlign.center,
                      style: TextStyle(
                        fontSize: 22,
                      ),
                    ),
                  ]),
            ),
          ),
          bottonButton(
            buttonTitle: 'Re-Calculate',
            onTap: () {
              Navigator.pop(context);
            },
          )
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

My Calculator brain page is as follows

```
class CalculatorBrain {
  CalculatorBrain({
    @required this.Getheight,
    @required this.Getweight,
  });

  final int Getheight;
  final int Getweight;
  double _bmi;

  String CalculateBMI() {
    double _bmi = Getweight / pow(Getheight / 100, 2);
    return _bmi.toStringAsFixed(1);
  }

  String getResult() {
    if (_bmi >= 25) {
      return 'Overweight';
    } else if (_bmi > 18.5) {
      return 'Normal';
    } else {
      return 'Underweight';
    }
  }

  String getInterpritation() {
    if (_bmi >= 25) {
      return 'You have a higher than normal body weight, Try excerise more';
    } else if (_bmi > 18.5) {
      return 'You have a Normal body weight, Good Job ! ';
    } else {
      return 'You have a Low than normal body weight, Try eating More !';
    }
  }
}
```

help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

```dart
  String CalculateBMI() {
    double _bmi = Getweight / pow(Getheight / 100, 2); // <--- variable shadowing
    return _bmi.toStringAsFixed(1);
  }
```

Here you are creating a new `_bmi` variable that is shadowing the class level variable of the same name. Remove the `double` part so you are assigning to the correct variable.

Comment: Swithced my code to this but the problem still exist 

 String CalculateBMI() {
    _bmi = (Getweight / pow(Getheight / 100, 2));
    return _bmi.toStringAsFixed(1);
  }

Comment: @RamGupta Here's a question. Why don't you just calculate the BMI in the constructor? What's the purpose of having it be a separate method?

Comment: i tried doing this the problem still exist

Comment: @RamGupta Then something else is going on that is not clear from your code samples. Is the instance of `CalculatorBrain` that you are generating the BMI on the same instance that your widget is reading from?